# Что делать, если в вопросе код не имеет отношения к формулируемой проблеме?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Иногда попадаются вопросы вида "Вот рабочий код*, решающий проблему А. Как решить проблему Б?" Причём связь между А и Б практически отсутствует, и решения для них совершенно различны. Что нужно предпринять в данном случае?

<sup>* Скорее всего, найденный на просторах интернета, а не написанный автором самостоятельно.</sup>

- Закрыть вопрос (по какой причине?)
- Поставить вопросу минус
- Отредактировать вопрос, убрав код
- *что-то ещё...*

Comment: Я просто прохожу мимо.

Comment: @Qwertiy, боюсь, это не решение проблемы - кому-то же придётся принимать решение по такому вопросу

Comment: Зачем? Если никто ничего не делает и не ставит плюсов, вопрос удалится духом через полгода.

Comment: это только при условии малого количества просмотров

Comment: Разве? Нулевой рейтинг и отсутствие комментариев и правок в течение полугода - по-моему всё. Сейчас поищу описание.

Comment: [Нашёл](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392/178988). Если вопросу более 365 дней и он имеет рейтинг 0 или рейтинг 1 и учетная запись автора удалена & не имеет ответов & не заблокирован & количество просмотров <= возраст вопроса в днях * 1.5 & имеет один или менее комментариев он будет удален. Много просмотров не будет, т. к. с главной он уползёт и сгинет, поэтому он всё равно удалится рано или поздно сам.

Comment: > _Много просмотров не будет_ - а вот это совсем ещё не факт, плюс комментариев ещё кто-то может настрочить, например, пытаясь выяснить, а что, собственно, автору нужно.

Comment: Число просмотров не будет увеличиваться, значит, рано или поздно вопорс удалится. А вот комментарии - да, могут появиться. Но если кто-то что-то хочет выяснить, то он, вероятно, в итоге и ответит. Если есть ответ, то код в вопросе уже не важен. Если нет ответа, автоудаление.

Comment: лишний код в вопросе может отвлекать будущих посетителей о сути проблемы (хотя, конечно, это уже не так критично - поисковики сейчас направляют пользователя прямо к ответу, не вопросу)

Comment: Конечно, *что-то еще...*. Если знаете, как решать проблему "Б", то расскажите об этом в ответе и объясните почему приведенный код не имеет никакого отношения к ее решению